# Accessing a MinIO bucket with rclone - can it be done through OpenID Connect (oidc)?

Tags: minio, oidc, openid-connect

I have the rights to access a personal bucket in a MinIO deployment in the cloud of my employer - I can easily access it via Firefox (after in-browser OpenID authentication through my employer IAM page) through the built-in file browser for the bucket but I cannot replicate the access through rclone.

In the rclone documentation I cannot find instructions (and I'm inclined to conclude it is not supported at the moment) on how to use the OpenID Connect agent (oidc) to authenticate access to an S3-compatible instance (as MinIO is, I believe, no?) - it seems to be available on for WebDAV while S3 instances require explicit access and secret keys in the .conf file or some env vars that I cannot find how to set.

I was able to install and configure the oidc client on my Fedora 39 and I have a working '**oidc-token ACCOUNT_NAME**' that returns a (hopefully working?) token (20 chars for access_key, 40 chars for secret_key) but even if I try unpacking it to obtain temporary S3 credentials (as explained [here](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/operations/external-iam/configure-openid-external-identity-management.html#id10)) to configure rclone it does not work with the message

> Failed to ls: InvalidTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.

What am I doing wrong?